# Import csv file with RIO with row.names = 1

Tags: r, csv, import, r-rio

I would like to know whether there is an argument like this one `(...,row.names = 1)` in the import function of RIO package. To get the same result as that argument in this line: `TVAds2 = read.csv("TVAds.csv", row.names=1)`.

I used the following argument `(..., row.names = TRUE)` unsuccessfully.

Comment: Try `import <- lapply(list.files(<path>), read.csv, row.names=1)`, no specific need for rio. `row.names=1` cares for first column being used as row names.